# A suggestion on answers: Include OS version and app version (if applicable)

Tags: discussion

Since Ice Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean are 25% of the active Android devices out there, but Gingerbread is still over 50% of the active devices, it occurs to me that instructions for changing settings may look very different to people with different devices. Sure, this was a problem before, but it's more pronounced now.

Anyway, my suggestion is that if you're including instructions to someone on how to change a setting in the OS or in an app, include the version of the OS (and app) you're using as a note in your answer.

Yes, I can envision having two separate answers saying virtually the same thing, the only difference being the OS version being referenced, but I don't think that's a bad thing. It's probably better than having nearly-but-not-quite duplicate questions, different only by the OS version.

Comment: I think this is a pretty fair point. Settings are quite different between versions of Android. Or even between different skins (Motoblur, Sense, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, perhaps we should revisit the "don't include OS-specific tags unless it truly is specific to the OS" rule. <del>[Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) works that way, insisting that you include a platform-specific tag if you're discussing a game that exists on multiple platforms.</del>

Comment: I'd say if there's a question about Android System settings, that should be sufficient to include a version tag. For other things it's at least worth mentioning the Android version, as e.g. a certain misbehaviour *could* be version specific.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is the same as what you're saying, but Arqade only includes the platform-specific tag if the platform is relevant.  Most questions apply across platforms.